# Call mysql SOURCE command from a C program

Tags: mysql, c

I want to execute some mysql statements that are stored in a text file from my C program using the mysql.h library.

My inclination was to do something like the following, but this doesn't work:

```
mysql_query(conn, "source test.mysql");
```

This is because the SOURCE command is not a mysql statement in and of itself.

Is there a way call the SOURCE command programmatically and not from the command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `source` command is a built-in command in the `mysql` client program, it isn't a SQL command.  Your best bet is to either call the `mysql` client program using the C `system` function (or an equivalent), or read the file text file yourself a command at a time and pass them to your query function.